# not fill model and set it in form in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**hi**

i have this model :

```
export interface SiteSetting {
    postSetting: PostSetting;
}

export interface PostSetting {
    showDataRecordAfterSomeDay: number;
}
```

and i need to fill model in component an add set to form value .

```
   postSettingAddFormGroup: FormGroup;
  postSettingModel: SiteSetting;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private postsettingService: PostService, private alertService: AlertService, private route: Router) {
    this.postSettingModel = {} as SiteSetting;
    this.cachedSetting();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.intialForm();
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }


  intialForm(): void {
    this.postSettingAddFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      showDataRecordAfterSomeDay: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(0), Validators.maxLength(365)])]
    });
  }

  cachedSetting(): void {
    this.postsettingService.getPostSetting().subscribe(data => {
      this.postSettingModel.postSettingsModel = data
    })
  }
```

i using this code but it not `postSettingModel` .

whats the problem? how can i solve this model ???

Comment: Are you getting any error? Need more detail about the actual problem.

Comment: @Prawinsoni nor i havent any error

Comment: If I understand it correct, you want to create a form and fill it with data from your PostSettingService?

Comment: @Laurent yes . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see is that you never connects your form with your fetched data. Try something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  postSettingAddFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private postSettingService: BtwService) {
    this.postSettingAddFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      showDataRecordAfterSomeDay: new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(0), Validators.maxLength(365)]))
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postSettingService.getPostSetting().subscribe(data => {
      this.postSettingAddFormGroup.patchValue({
        showDataRecordAfterSomeDay: data.showDataRecordAfterSomeDay
      });
    });
  }
}
```

First, move your form creating in the constructor.

"showDataRecordAfterSomeDay" is a number so you have to init this as null or 0 instead of ''.

Now, to update your form with your data, you can use "PatchValue". This is what happens in ngOnInit.

In your HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="postSettingAddFormGroup">
  <input type="text" formControlName="showDataRecordAfterSomeDay">
</form>
```

In the PostSettingService, I asume you are returning a PostSetting? So:

```
getPostSetting(): Observable<PostSetting> {
    return of({showDataRecordAfterSomeDay: 10});
}
```

Comment: @kianoushdortaj what are you returning in the getPostSetting() Observable<SiteSetting> of Observable<PostSetting>?

I edited the solution with html and service